# Draw an ERD from Hibernate Mapping Files

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, netbeans, erd

I know it's possible to reverse engineer from the database into mapping files but does anyone know if it's possible to get hibernate to draw an ERD based on its own mapping files so that I can  compare Hibernate's ERD with the Databases one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by using:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
```

in my hibernate.cfg.xml

Then I used MySQL Workbench to reverse engineer an ERD from my database that was created by Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. As far as I know you can't do it directly from the mappings but instead you have to generate the database first.

What you have to do is simple:

1. Create your database by your mapping
2. Open (or download) MySQL Workbench
3. Create a new Database Model Diagram
4. Go to Database > Reverse Engineer and fill in your database details.
5. Next steps should be easy for you

Comment: You're just repeating what I said.

Answer (score 0):

By Default hibernate creates MySql MyIsam Database which has internal connections instead of foreign keys so MySQL WORCKBENCH or VISUAL PARADIGM wont show ERD properly with connections make sure in application.properties inside resources to create this statement.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
```

instead of

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

which creates MyISAM, watch for the double 5 this is the key here to change mode